# how to send some data periodically using volley in service in android

Tags: android, google-maps, service, gps, android-volley

I am working on a location based app, I want to send location updates every 10 seconds to server using service class. Can anybody tell how to do this with volley? Basically I want to achieve real time location tracking. Any kind of help will be appreciated.
If need more info, kindly comment.

Comment: you don't know how to run method periodically, or how to send data to server?

Comment: how to run method periodically in background

Comment: you can use `Handler.postDelayed()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the same by using below code 
Call this method in your activity class

```
  private void startLocationUpdate() {
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourReceiver.class);
//        boolean flag = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
//                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);
       /*Register alarm if not registered already*/
        // if (flag) {
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Create Calendar obj called calendar
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

           /* Setting alarm for every time interval from the current time.*/
        int intervalTimeMillis = 1000 * interval; // time interval for updating location
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), intervalTimeMillis,
                alarmIntent);
        // }
    }
```

Create a broadastReceiver class like this

```
public class UpdateLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, LocationUpdateService.class);
    context.startService(startIntent);
}
```

}

and create an intent service for updating your location to server using volley

```
public class LocationUpdateService extends IntentService {
private static String tagName = "LocationUpdateService";

public LocationUpdateService() {
    super(tagName);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    updateLocation();
}

private void updateLocation() {
   // your volley code for updating location to server
}
```

}

and dont forget to mention your receiver in manifest file

Comment: `AlarmManager` won't let you use periods less than 60 seconds

Comment: You can stop this by canceling the alarm using same pending intent that you used for starting . Follow this tutorial http://code4reference.com/2012/07/tutorial-on-android-alarmmanager/

Comment: Ok Thanks,
Now can you tell me how to trace the locations continuously and move the marker on map ?

Comment: You can set location enabled true to your map , implement locationChanged listener to your mapActivity and in onLocationChange method set your marker

Comment: No, I want to get the locations of any other user and trace in on my map.